# Using Chi-Square-Test for single item likert type hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, survey, likert

I conducted a Survey to find reasons why firms invest in a specific asset.
I asked them in a Likert-question if different aspects are a reason to invest in [asset]. The Response for each aspect can be:

- strongly agree (sa)
- agree (a)
- neutral
- disagree (d)
- strongly disagree (sd)

Now my question is: Is it appropriate to use a **Chi-Square** test for each aspect to investigate if this aspect is in favor or against the firm investing? I.e. testing if the distribution of Responses (sa + a) and (sd + d) is significant different than the total number of non-neutral answers / 2.

Thank you!

(If this matters: For some aspects I have an expected tendency from Theory, for other aspects I do not know what to expect)

---

My data looks somewhat like in the image.

### [image: My collected data looks like this (values are numbers of respondents):]

---

**Example**

For Aspect 1 I would calculate the positive answers: 6+7=13 and the negative answers 3+1=4 and then do a Chi-Square test against the expected equal distribution of all non-neutral answers: (6+7+3+1)/2=8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chi-Square / Fisher's exact test is not the right choice here, since it doesn't acknowledge the ordinality of the Likert scale.

Instead you should do a Kruskal-Wallis test (Friedmann test if data are paired) where your Aspects are the factors and the Likert scale is the outcome (you cannot do ANOVA since normality/interval scale assumptions don't hold for Likert scale). This test assesses if there is ANY Aspect that's significantly different from the others. This KW test should be significant. Afterwards you can do a multiple testing procedure, more precisely the Dunn test (with Bonferroni correction), where you test pairwise Aspects for significance. This should show which aspects are in agreement/disagreement.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: These procedures should be available in common statistics software. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using R (PMCMR package). Reading into it at the moment.

Comment: May I ask a follow up question: Did I understand this right: The significant Kruskal Wallis test shows me that there are differences between the items. And the post-hoc Dunn test shows me which aspects are significantly different from each other.
I think this is a bit Overkill, since I just need to prove if single items (aspects) are perceived positive or negative. I do not need to make a link between items.

Comment: Some confusion in terminology: items = items of the Likert scale (strongly agree, ..., strongly disagree), aspects = factor groups for the KW test

Comment: Yes, you're right, the KW test is for assessing if any aspect/factor group differs significantly from the others in its distribution (on the items), and the post-hoc tests identify which aspects are different from the others.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I read (e.g. Wikipedia) of Likert-type "items" as single questions and Likert scale as a matrix-Kind-of construct with multiple "items".

Comment: If you do not make a link between aspects, you might want to do a one-sample Wilcoxon signed rank test (wilcox.test(x, mu=0, alternative="greater) in R). It tests whether the distribution of x is positively skewed above mu=0, where 0 would be the item "neutral". Don't forget (Bonferroni) correction for the p-values if you test all aspects separately.

Comment: So I try to clarify what I want to do: 
I try to prove that individual aspects are positively (or negatively) perceived, based on Theory.
H0: There is no dominant opinion about this aspect
H1: This aspect is positive perceived

There is no Need to compare across aspects.

Edit: just saw your response! Thank you!!

Comment: Buuuuut... How good is your assumption that there's no link between the aspects? All of the aspects were rated by the same firms. E.g. most of your firms might tend to answer on the "agree" side of the Likert scale, while only some would answer on the "disagree" side. All of the Wilcoxon-tests would be significant, but actually it's just the difference between firms. The Kruskal-Wallis/Friedman test would be non-signifcant, since all firms would answer roughly the same across aspects.

Comment: Well I ran the Kruskal-Wallis test as suggested and it was highly significant.
Also when i run Wilcoxon tests, i get 8 aspects to be significant "greater" and i get 2 aspects to be "less" and 5 aspects wich are never significant different from 0.

Comment: Nice! You should set the Wilcoxon test to alternative="two-sided" if you don't want to make any assumption about the direction beforehand. Otherwise the workflow 1) Kruskal-Wallis 2) Wilcoxon with multiple testing correction should be fine now for your investigation (imho).

Comment: I know one shouldn't write comments to say "thanks" but you really helped me a lot! I appreciate it! thank you!

Comment: Would the presence of "don't know" in the response options change the answer to this question?